# How to prove strict inequality holds for no in Agda

Tags: agda, inequality, negation

I am currently working on one of the recommended question from the chapter Negation in [plfa](https://plfa.github.io/Negation/)

Here is the question description:

```
Using negation, show that strict inequality is irreflexive, that is, n < n holds for no n.
```

From my understanding, I think in strict inequality, it will take two natural numbers as the argument and output a set right? :

```
data _<_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set where

    z<s : ∀ {n : ℕ}
        ------------
      → zero < suc n

    s<s : ∀ {m n : ℕ}
      → m < n
        -------------
      → suc m < suc n
```

And here is my definition of irreflexive:

```
<-irreflexive : ∀ {n : ℕ} → n < n → ⊥
<-irreflexive n<n = ?
```

I know that I need to achieve a "⊥" in the RHS. And since "n<n" is a set, I try to use ¬, but the complier says "n<n" :`(n < n) !=< Set`. So, what is the type of "n<n" in this case? And am I approaching right in this question? Could anybody give me a hint on that? Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track! The trick is now to use the argument `n<n` for which there can be no real element to produce something of type `⊥`. We do this by pattern matching on `n<n`. Agda can already see that the constructor `z<s` can't possibly apply (this is morally equivalent of producing something of type `⊥`) so all that's left to do is to handle the `s<s` case:

```
<-irreflexive : ∀ {n : ℕ} → n < n → ⊥
<-irreflexive (s<s n<n) = ?
```

However, we can now use recursion to produce the required element of type `⊥`

```
<-irreflexive : ∀ {n : ℕ} → n < n → ⊥
<-irreflexive (s<s n<n) = <-irreflexive n<n
```

Tada, done!

Comment: Also, since I am totally new to functional programming. Just want to how do you usually solve some specific problems? I feel like sometimes, I am  quite close to the answers but always can not get the last the step, which is a bit frustrating..